# How to know what android:id Android expects?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source, android-2.2-froyo

In some android classes you can set a custom layout. As far as my understanding goes, these custom layouts need certain `android:id`s to work.

For example, for the `ListActivity` a `ListView` with `@android:id/list` has to be provided and this is specified in the documentation.

What about other views? For example, I was checking the API Demos and came across

```
<CheckBoxPreference
                android:key="child_checkbox_preference"
                android:dependency="parent_checkbox_preference"
                android:layout="?android:attr/preferenceLayoutChild"
                android:title="@string/title_child_preference"
                android:summary="@string/summary_child_preference" />
```

There's a layout specified for the preference. That layout seems to be `preference_child.xml`, in which there's `@+android:id/title` and `@+android:id/summary`, which I assume the view will use to provide the title and the summary, but is this documented anywhere?

How do I know what resource IDs I have to use so that everything automagically works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no trick to find out but to know the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html) or open the android's id.xml and look for references.

P.S.
Your code demonstrates how to use a specific attribute out of an entire style (the use of "?"), it has nothing to do with ID's

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that's an attribute, but it's referring to a layout. My point was that I could take that and make it refer to @layout/my_checkbox_layout, but then, how do I know what I have to put exactly in that layout so that I get all the "default benefits"?